# Como atribuir recuperar o ip de um serviço dentro do docker-composer?

Tags: docker, zabbix, yaml

Estou tentando levantar o zabbix no docker, eu criei um docker-compose com vários serviços, um deles é o banco de dados. 
Eu preciso levantar o banco de dados primeiro e depois pegar o ip do banco de dados e setar na variável de ambiente de outros serviços, porém não sei como fazer, já tentei usar o links, mas não estou tendo sucesso.

Esse é o meu docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
mysql-zabbix :
  image: "mysql:5.7"
  ports:
    - "53306:3306"
  networks:
    - net_zabbix
  volumes:
    - "vol_db_zabbix:/var/lib/mysql"
  environment:
    - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abcd"
    - "MYSQL_DATABASE=zabbix"
    - "MYSQL_USER=zabbix"
    - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456"

zabbix-server:
  image: "zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-3.4.11"
  ports:
    - "10051:10051"
  networks:
    - net_zabbix
  environment:
    - "DB_SERVER_PORT=53306"
    - DB_SERVER_HOST=zabbix.db
    - "MYSQL_USER=zabbix"
    - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456"
  depends_on:
    - mysql-zabbix
  external_links:
    - mysql-zabbix:zabbix.db

zabbix-web:
  image: "zabbix/zabbix-web-apache-mysql:alpine-3.4.11"
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  networks:
    - net_zabbix
  environment:
    - DB_SERVER_HOST=zabbix.db
    - "DB_SERVER_PORT=53306"
    - "MYSQL_USER=zabbix"
    - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456"
    - ZBX_SERVER_HOST=zabbix.server
    - "PHP_TZ=America/Sao_Paulo"
  depends_on:
    - zabbix-server
  external_links:
    - mysql-zabbix:zabbix.db
    - zabbix-server:zabbix.server

zabbix-agent:
  image: "zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-3.4.11"
  ports:
    - "10050:10050"
  networks:
    - net_zabbix
  environment:
    - "ZBX_HOSTNAME=demo_zabbix"
    - ZBX_SERVER_HOST=zabbix.server
  external_links:
    - zabbix-server:zabbix.server

zabbix-proxy:
  image: "zabbix/zabbix-proxy-sqlite3:alpine-3.4.11"
  ports:
    - "10053:10050"
  networks:
    - net_zabbix
  environment:
    - "ZBX_HOSTNAME=demo_zabbix"
    - ZBX_SERVER_HOST=zabbix.server
  external_links:
    - zabbix-server:zabbix.server

networks:
net_zabbix:

volumes:
vol_db_zabbix:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando alguns conceitos de forma errada, como o uso de [`external_links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external_links). `external_links` são usados apenas quando é necessário um *link* com *container* criado/gerenciado fora da *compose* em questão. Estando na mesma rede e *compose* nem mesmo [`links`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links) são necessários, sendo estes obsoletos atualmente, sendo preferível gerir acesso a *containers* através de *networks*.

Dito isto, a primeira coisa é remover TODOS os `external_links` da *compose*. Feito isso, agora podemos corrigir os nomes dos containers referenciados nas variáveis de ambiente. Para facilitar não irei usar *link aliases*, ou seja, `zabbix.db` passa a ser `mysql-zabbix` e `zabbix.server` passa a ser `zabbix-server`.

Uma outra observação: como estão na mesma rede não é necessário publicar a porta do *mysql*, principalmente em outra porta, configurando-a no zabbix. Na mesma rede as portas expostas pelos *containers* são acessíveis a todos os outros *containers* na mesma rede.

Uma versão final possível seria a abaixo:

```
version: "2"
services:
  mysql-zabbix:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - net_zabbix
    volumes:
      - vol_db_zabbix:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abcd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=zabbix
      - MYSQL_USER=zabbix
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456

  zabbix-server:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-3.4.11
    ports:
      - "10051:10051"
    networks:
      - net_zabbix
    environment:
      - DB_SERVER_HOST=mysql-zabbix
      - MYSQL_USER=zabbix
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
    depends_on:
      - mysql-zabbix

  zabbix-web:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-web-apache-mysql:alpine-3.4.11
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - net_zabbix
    environment:
      - DB_SERVER_HOST=mysql-zabbix
      - MYSQL_USER=zabbix
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456
      - PHP_TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
    depends_on:
      - zabbix-server

  zabbix-agent:
    image: "zabbix/zabbix-agent:alpine-3.4.11"
    ports:
      - "10050:10050"
    networks:
      - net_zabbix
    environment:
      - ZBX_HOSTNAME=demo_zabbix

  zabbix-proxy:
    image: zabbix/zabbix-proxy-sqlite3:alpine-3.4.11
    ports:
      - "10053:10050"
    networks:
      - net_zabbix
    environment:
      - ZBX_HOSTNAME=demo_zabbix

networks:
  net_zabbix:

volumes:
  vol_db_zabbix:
```

Valide a configuração do *proxy*, já que ele não é encontrado. Não sei em detalhes como o *zabbix* funciona, então revise-a.

Alguns valores são *default*, conforme a documentação das imagens no *Docker Hub*, então foram omitidas (como a `ZBX_SERVER_HOST`). Por último, como comentando, você poderá criar *aliases* usando os `links` para manter o mesmo nome, por clareza e simplicidade costumo manter o nome dos *services* mesmo.